# Php using strip_tags to ignore text in <a> tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

I want to strip tags. 
When I use

```
$ta=strip_tags($_REQUEST['textarea'],'<a>');
```

it returns `<a>` tags. 
If I use

```
$ta=strip_tags($_REQUEST['textarea']);
```

it includes the interior of the `<a href>`.

I want only text. For example with this html

```
$text= '<p>test paragraph.</p>'<a href="index.php">Click link</a>';
```

I want only `test paragraph`, but I'm getting `test paragraph.Click link`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Using `strip_tags($_REQUEST['textarea']);` you will get only text? Also the setting of `$text` is not syntactically correct. (You can see that the highlighting fails)

Comment: at the last code example strip_tags($text) will give me "test paragraph.Click Link" but I want only "test paragraph"

Comment: You probably need to specify what you mean by text. What about a table? Is that text or not?

Comment: table is not a content. its a html marking. so I dont want table,div,p,span or another html markings. But I want content in them. But I dont want content in an a tag.

Comment: So it's only `<a>` tag you want to exclude? Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only `<a href` tags you don't like as commented in the comments above this should clear them away and leave you with the rest that can be easily removed with strip_tags().

```
$text= '<p>test paragraph.</p><a href="index.php">Click link</a><p>test paragraph.</p><a href="index.php">Click link</a><p>test paragraph.</p>';

$pos = strpos($text, "<a href"); // find first a href

while($pos !== false){ // loop until there is no more a href
    $pos2 = strpos($text, "</a>", $pos)+4; // find the end tag of the a
    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos) . substr($text, $pos2); // remove the tag and link text
    $pos = strpos($text, "<a href"); // find the next. If none is found "false" is returned meaning while ends.
}

echo strip_tags($text); // strip away other tags.
```

https://3v4l.org/YtJic

Comment: Output is : 

    test paragraph.test paragraph.test paragraph.
it should be

test paragraph <a href="index.php">Click link</a> test paragraph.